# while trying to fetch data,i get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not iterable"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am noob at this, so what i am trying to do is   fetch the data of pokeapi.co (pokemon api), so i get an an array with objects,each object has an url, this url you can fetch it and  get all the info about the current pokemon...It works fine until i try to map the array with all the object inside and shows the following error...(i tried to use async/await buti not sure how to use it...Help!)

```
import Card from "./card"
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react"

function App() {

const [pokemon,setPokemon]=useState()
const[loading,setLoading]=useState(true)

useEffect(
 async ()=>{
    
        return await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=20&offset=20")
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then( async data=>{return await data.results.map(async element=>{return await fetch(element.url).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{return setPokemon(prevState=>{return [...prevState,{data}]})})})})}
    
,[])
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header id="header" className="py-10 w-full bg-yellow-500">
        <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-bold text-red-700">Pokedex.</h1>
      </header>

     {loading &&  <div class="rounded-t-lg overflow-hidden border-t border-l border-r  text-center p-4 py-12">
        <span class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
          <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150 cursor-not-allowed" disabled="">
            <svg class="animate-spin -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="4"></circle>
              <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor" d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"></path>
            </svg>
            Processing
          </button>
        </span>
        </div>}
    
      <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 my-10  px-10">
         {pokemon? pokemon.results.map((element,index)=>{return <Card key={index} name={ element.name.toUpperCase()} />}):null} 
      </div>
        <footer className="text-center text-gray-500 font-bold">2020</footer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

when i fetch this(https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=20&offset=20) i get this[image]
So i try to fetch each url inside the object to get all the info about the current  pokemon, so the response is this
[image]
and what i want to do is save this data in state to render it later

im lost with the usage of async/await... If you have a better idea  how to implement this, would be great!!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bTR9.png]

Comment: Mixing `await` with `.then()` callbacks just leads to confusing code. Stick to one convention

Comment: Looks like the error is saying your `pokemon` state value isn't iterable, so it can't be spread. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example. I agree with @Phil, the async/await looks to be completely superfluous since the effect *never* handles an awaited return value.

Comment: `await data.results.map` makes no sense since `data.results.map` returns an Array, not a Promise

Comment: also ... `[...prevState, { data }]` would mean the same `data:` property would be overwritten every iteration - so, you'd end up with one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. Effect hook callback are synchronously processed, they can't be `async`
2. `pokemon` initial state is undefined, so it isn't iterable
3. `setPokemon` treats `pokemon` state like it is an array, but `pokemon` state is later accessed as if it were an object, i.e. `pokemon.results`
4. The loading state is never cleared
5. All the pokemon `data` is nested in a `data` key, but accessed as if the data were all at the root level, i.e. `element.name.toUpperCase()`

minor issues

1. Use `className` versus `class` in JSX
2. Use camelCased attributes, i.e. `strokeWidth` versus `stroke-width`

## Solution

Provide initial state, I suggest an array. Now the previous state is iterable

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
```

Render the array directly. Try to avoid using an array index as the react key.

```
{pokemon.map((element) => <Card key={element.id} name={element.name.toUpperCase()} />)}
```

Stick to promise chain, or async/await.

`useEffect` using promise chain. Add a catch block for handling errors, and a finally block to clear the loading state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=20&offset=20")
    // Return response JSON object promise
    .then((res) => res.json())

    // Map array of fetch request promises
    .then((data) => Promise.all(data.results.map((el) => fetch(el.url))))

    // Map array of response JSON object promises
    .then((results) => Promise.all(results.map((res) => res.json())))

    // Update state, copy old state and append new
    .then((data) => setPokemon((pokemon) => [...pokemon, ...data]))

    .catch((error) =>
      console.error("There has been a problem with your fetch operation:", error)
    )
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);
```

[image: Edit while-trying-to-fetch-data-i-get-unhandled-rejection-typeerror-undefined-is (Promise Chain)]

`useEffect` using async/await. Wrap all the fetching logic within an `async` function and invoke *that* in the effect hook callback. Add a catch block for handling errors, and a finally block to clear the loading state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const pokeFetch = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=20&offset=20");

      // Await response JSON object promise
      const data = await res.json();

      // Await map array of fetch request promises
      const urlRes = await Promise.all(data.results.map((el) => fetch(el.url)));

      // Await map array of response JSON object promise
      const results = await Promise.all(urlRes.map((res) => res.json()));

      // Update state, copy old state and append new
      setPokemon((pokemon) => [...pokemon, ...results]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("There has been a problem with your fetch operation:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  pokeFetch();
}, []);
```

[image: Edit while-trying-to-fetch-data-i-get-unhandled-rejection-typeerror-undefined-is (Async/Await)]

JSX render. Use `className` and `strokeWidth` attributes. Map `pokemon` unconditionally, the `array.prototype.map` will handle the empty array state without issue.

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header id="header" className="py-10 w-full bg-yellow-500">
      <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-bold text-red-700">
        Pokedex.
      </h1>
    </header>

    {loading && (
      <div className="rounded-t-lg overflow-hidden border-t border-l border-r  text-center p-4 py-12">
        <span className="inline-flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150 cursor-not-allowed"
            disabled=""
          >
            <svg
              className="animate-spin -ml-1 mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-white"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <circle
                className="opacity-25"
                cx="12"
                cy="12"
                r="10"
                stroke="currentColor"
                strokeWidth="4"
              ></circle>
              <path
                className="opacity-75"
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
            Processing
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    )}

    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 my-10  px-10">
      {pokemon.map((element) => (
        <Card key={element.id} name={element.name.toUpperCase()} />
      ))}
    </div>
    <footer className="text-center text-gray-500 font-bold">2020</footer>
  </div>
);
```